# Finding duplicate **Set of Values** in multiple rows in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database table with this sample data:

```
 ProductID     GenericID       MG
 ---------------------------------
    1           1           2g 
    1           2           5g
    2           2           5g
    3           1           2g
    3           2           5g
    4           1           2g
    5           1           2g
    5           3           7g
    6           2           5g
    7           1           2g
    8           1           2g
```

I want to find out the query to select data

1. if I select `ProductID=1` then the query should check what `GenericID` are associated with `ProductID=1`
2. In above data case if user select `ProductID=1` then query will check `GenericID=`1 and 2 are associated with `ProductID=1`.
3. Then after I want to go through all rows and select those rows who has the same Unique `ProductID` and also having only `GenericID=1 and 2`.
4. as in above case the final output will be as shown below....
5. I select `ProductID=1` and output has four rows, because only ProductId 3 has same `GenericID` as were of `ProductId=1`.

If I select only `ProductId=1` then I want to get all the rows with the same exact set of `GenericID` values as `ProductID=1`, which is the set `{ 1, 2 }` in my sample data. I am struggling with the query logic.

For example - I select `ProductID=1`, this is the output that I want is as follows, because `ProductID` 3 has the same set of `GenericID` values as `ProductID` 1.

```
     ProductID    GenericID     MG
     -------------------------------
        1              1        2g     
        1              2        5g
        3              1        2g
        3              2        5g
```

`GenericID` can be on or multiple dynamic values.

Another example - if I select `ProductID=7`, this is the output I want:

In this example -  It will only get those results that are having only GenericID=1 because `ProductID`=7 has only `GenericID`=1. any set of productID which is having `GenericID=1` and also that set includes other `GenericID` will be neglected.

```
      ProductID    GenericID     MG
      ------------------------------
        7              1         2g    
        8              1         2g
        4              1         2g
```

I need to find out the query to select the required output.
I want all of the products that have the same set of generic id's as the predicate product.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is probably to use `string_agg()`:

```
with t as (
      select productID, string_agg(genericId, ',') within group (order by genericId) as genericIds
      from sample
      group by productID
     )
select s.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t.genericIds = t2.genericIds and t2.productId = 1 join
     sample s
     on s.productId = t.productId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon, thanks a lot for your prompt response, basically I forget to inform you that I am using SQL 2014 and that's why **string_agg():** action function wasn't helpful for me but I really appreciate your help and the prompt response that make my day. Here I created my query with the help of your other query and you became and very helpful resource for me.

```
select PG.PID2 as Alternatives
from (select d1.ProductID as PID1, d2.ProductID as PID2
      from (select distinct ProductID from ProductsGenerics Where ProductID=@PID) d1 cross join
           (select distinct ProductID from ProductsGenerics) d2
     ) PG left outer join
     ProductsGenerics e1
     on e1.ProductID = PG.PID1 full outer join
     ProductsGenerics e2
     on PG.PID2 = e2.ProductID and e1.genericid = e2.GenericID-- and e1.MG = e2.MG
group by PG.PID1, PG.PID2
having SUM(case when e1.GenericID is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       SUM(case when e2.GenericID is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```